# Boas práticas para URI em API Restful usando Laravel

Tags: rest, restful, laravel-4

Boa tarde,

Estou tendo construir minhas rotas utilizando o padrão REST, porém quero fazer isso  utilizando as ferramentas que o Laravel me oferece, e do modo correto. tenho a seguinte rota para imprimir minhas ordens de serviço:

```
 ..\ordensdeservico\{id}\impressoes\{tipoImpressao}
```

Seria correto eu utilizar (vou apenas imprimir):

```
   Route::resource(['ordensdeservico' => "OsController"], function () {
         Route::resource(['impressoes' => "ImpressaoOsController"])->only(['index']);
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para aninhar uma rota, `\ordensdeservico\{id}\impressoes\{tipoImpressao}` por exemplo, o Laravel utiliza *'Nested Resources'*, o exemplo de como ficaria utilizando a *'Nested Resources'*:

```
   Route::resource('ordens_de_servico','OsController');
   Route::resource('ordens_de_servico.impressoes','ImpressaoOsController');
```

Sendo assim, por padrão ele chamaria função *show()* do Controller *'ImpresaoOSController'*, para cada verbo REST utilizado ele chamaria a seu respectivo método equivalente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As informações acima foram retiradas do link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers e https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards